# Jquery UI API for offline viewing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using **Jquery-ui** majorly for displaying progressbar and also using the basic jquery api as the scripting language in my html page.

I have linked all the jquery and its UI api to google API link. So, this requires the user to be always connected to internet.

Also, the users are not expected to download these libraries in their machines, so that if stored at some fixed location, I can point to those libraries.

Is there any way out , to use the html for offline viewing i.e when the user is not at all connected to internet ?

One option I am having is to copy the source of jquery and JQuery-UI into my HTML report :P.But I am certainly looking for other options.

Comment: Are you talking about mobile devices? Browser extensions? Please do elaborate as this isn't very clear to as how your html page is accessible if they don't have access to the internet. And in fact, linking those libraries from Google will most likely reduce the likelihood that they won't be available if the user for some reason loses internet connection at some point, as they are in so many cases already cached from your or one of the other millions of sites using them.

Comment: @Niklas: I am generating an HTML based report on some statistics which is calculated by a perl script. This script feeds data into the html and what I get is a tabular view of data with progressbar. So I want the users to be able to view this report even if there is no connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, those libraries will be cached by the visitor's browsers and will be available, provided the visitor does not clear his/her cache.

**EDIT**

Reading in the comments that

> I am generating an HTML based report
>   on some statistics which is calculated
>   by a perl script. This script feeds
>   data into the html and what I get is a
>   tabular view of data with progressbar.
>   So I want the users to be able to view
>   this report even if there is no
>   connection.

I say your only option is to place the scripts (source) directly in your HTML page.

Comment: Certainly I cannot hope for that :)

Comment: Yes that is what I did . I removed lots of ui widget codes which I was not using from the jquery-ui library and the resulting library size was pretty less :)

Answer (score 0):

Download jQuery and the UI bundle to your local server, serve it from there. I assume this is some internal network, since if the users didn't have internet access they wouldn't be able to view your site.

Comment: Thanks but please check the comment I have posted in response to Niklas comment

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the content of your js files (jquery, jquery ui) into `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here  you can find any offline documantion. (www.helpmesh.net)

For jQuery & jQuery UI:
http://www.helpmesh.net/s/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

Not the same format as the online jquery doc, but at first glance, this looks useful: http://www.jqapi.com/

Comment: I don't think you intended to answer this 5 year old question :)